# Two-dimensional array initialization values

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working on a program using arrays and I'm trying to figure out

First, with the following array declaration, what is the value stored in the `scores[2][2]` element?

```
int scores[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3} };
```

And also with this array declaration, what is the value stored in the `scores[2][3]` element?

```
int scores[5][5] = {5};
```

Could someone please explain this for me.

Comment: All unset values are set to `0` in this case.

Comment: Try it. Three lines of code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array indexing is zero-based.

Which means that for: `int foo[3] = {10, 20, 30};`

- `foo[0]` is 10
- `foo[1]` is 20
- `foo[2]` is 30

For multidimensional arrays, you should think of them as arrays of arrays.

So this would create an array containing two `int[3]`s: `int foo[2][3] = {{10, 20, 30}, {40, 50, 60}};`

- `foo[0][0]` is 10
- `foo[0][1]` is 20
- `foo[0][2]` is 30
- `foo[1][0]` is 40
- `foo[1][1]` is 50
- `foo[1][2]` is 60

C supports partial initialization. In which it will default all non initialized values to 0.

So if you were to do this: `int foo[3] = {5};`

- `foo[0]` is 5
- `foo[1]` is 0
- `foo[2]` is 0

Similarly for a multidimensional array: `int foo[2][3] = {5};`

- `foo[0][0]` is 5
- `foo[0][1]` is 0
- `foo[0][2]` is 0
- `foo[1][0]` is 0
- `foo[1][1]` is 0
- `foo[1][2]` is 0

Comment: @michaelm Don't forget to accept either [Yu Hao](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1009479/yu-hao)'s answer or my answer if one of them answered your question.

Answer (score 6):

```
int scores[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3} };
```

is equivalent to:

```
int scores[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
```

The other one is similar. You know the answer.

Comment: I got that part, they only thing I wasn't sure about is identifying the value.

Comment: @michaelm If you got this part, the rest is easy, the only thing I think worth mentioning is indexing starts from `0`.

Comment: So since I have a 2D array (a row/column grid), but only specified the first line, so the rest get initialized to zero so I should expect the code to write zero right?

Comment: @michaelm As long as there's an initializer, all the elements not explicitly initialized are initialized to `0`. For instance, `int scores[3][3] = {}` sets all elements to `0`.